# Solving $a^3 - 33 ab^2 = -217$ and $3a^2 b - 11b^3 = 18$?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, cubics

I am looking for ways of solving systems like that:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{lcl} a^3 - 33 ab^2 = -217 \\ 3a^2 b - 11b^3 = 18 \end{array} \right.$$

I've tried turning it into a system of 2 equations with 4 variables but then, having the relations and 4 degrees of freedom makes it equally difficult. Are there any catches one could apply here?

Answer (score 5):

Does this help?
$$(a-\sqrt{11} i b)^3 = a^3-3\sqrt{11}i a^2 b -33ab^2+11\sqrt{11}ib^3$$
$$=(a^3 -33ab^2)-\sqrt{11}i(3 a^2 b-11b^3)$$
$$=-217-\sqrt{11} \, 18 \, i$$

Comment: Interesting.  I would instead have focused on $\displaystyle ~(a + \sqrt{11} i b)^3.$  However, I haven't really thought the matter through, so, far all I know, your approach may be better.

Comment: It looks to me like the two approaches correspond on making a sign change on $b.$

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt[3]{11}$?

Comment: $\displaystyle r^3e^{i(3\theta)} = z^3 \implies z = re^{i\theta}.$

Comment: @RobertB. No, that is not what he intends.  See my last comment, and think about DeMoivre's Theorem, that $~\displaystyle \left[e^{i\theta}\right]^n = e^{i n\theta}.$

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the other approaches you would like to try.

Multiply the first equation by $18$, multiply the second one by $217$, then add them together, we get:

$18a^3-18*33ab^2+217*3a^2b-217*11b^3=0$

$\Leftrightarrow 18a^3+651a^2b-594ab^2-2387b^3=0$

The last equation is homogeneous of degree 3, so you could solve the associate cubic equation to compute $a$ by $b$ (Luckily this cubic equation has a rational root).

Comment: I struggle to see why is it 3-homogenous. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @RobertB. You just look at the terms of the LHS. 18a^3 has degree 3, 651a^2b has degree 2+1=3, 594ab^2 has degree 1+2=3, and 2387b^3 has degree 3 too. So the LHS is 3-homogeneous.

Ah, and to find the associate cubic equation, all you have to do is just divide two side by b. Of course, remember the case b=0 before dividing :D

Answer (score 3):

Taking the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $p=a^3-33ab^2+217$ and $q=3a^2b-11b^3-18$ with respect to $b$ immediately gives
$$
(4a^4 - 14a^3 + 111a^2 + 217a + 961)(4a^2 + 14a + 49)(2a^2 + 7a - 31)(2a - 7)=0.
$$
Hence the only rational solution is
$$
(a,b)=\left( \frac{7}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right).
$$
The quadratic equation $2a^2+7a-31=0$ yields
$$
(a,b)=\left( \frac{-7\pm 3\sqrt{33}}{2},\frac{-33\pm 7\sqrt{33}}{2}\right)
$$
Similarly we can solve the quadratic equation $4a^2 + 14a + 49=0$, which has non-real solutions. The quartic equation has four non-real roots.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how do you get $b$?

Comment: Actually, already $${\rm resultant}(a^3-33ab^2+217,3a^2b-11b^3-18,a)=(484b^4 - 726b^3 + 1221b^2 + 198b + 36)(22b^2 + 33b - 6)(4b^2 + 6b + 9)(2b - 3)=0,$$ so that we are done immediately. And taking the resultant of these with respect to $b$ gives exactly the condition in my answer for $a$.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that it is hard to arrive at the factorised form of the resultant. Did you use e.g. Wolframalpha to compute it?

Comment: Yes, I did not compute this by hand. Systems of cubic equations usually require a CAS. By the way, by the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) it is not hard to find the rational root.

Comment: Sure, but once there are non-rational roots we are doomed. So this methods can't really work without a computer.

Comment: I still think it is reasonable to use a computer here. That's the way equations are usually solved, and not by hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, the purpose of this question is to find a directly computable method. Otherwise, I can ask Mathematica for solutions directly.

Comment: Then the other answers also do not help so far. I think without a computer we only can find easily the unique rational root by the rational root test. For the quartic equation we cannot find the roots without computer, I think. So this exercise is not solvable without a computer anyway - if you do not agree, let me know how you found the four nonreal solutions of $4a^4-\cdots +961=0$.

Comment: And, by the way, did you try to ask Mathematica directly (with "solve") for the solutions? What happened?